# Label encoding in Azure Machine Learning Studio

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to find the equivalent of the sklearn [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) or the [OrdinalEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder) in Azure ML Studio. I understand the Convert to Indicator Values module performs One-hot encoding but I can't find anything that would do label encoding.

What I have is a column with six unique string values and what I need is to represent that data with integers from 0 to 6.

Right now, I'm using the Execute Python Script module to do it but I was wondering if there's a built-in module to do it.

Comment: Small question - why do you want to represent the data as integers? Is this a hard requirement, or do you simply want to mark the feature as representing a category?

Answer (score 1):

There is [Feature Hashing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/feature-hashing) module that converts strings to integer encoded features using the Vowpal Wabbit library. It builds a dictionary and based on this dictionary converts its items into hash values. So instead of having a string column you will have your data in the following format:

```
Hashing feature 1   Hashing feature 2   Hashing feature 3
1                   0                   0
```